# TagHelper is not rendered or displayed in IntelliSense

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a Visual Studio 2017 project and need to start implementing some Tag Helpers.

I started by following this tutorial [Authoring Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring)  but it is not working at all; The IntelliSense doesn't work, nothing ... as this is a relatively new project, I am presuming that a reference is missing but I cannot figure out what exactly.

EmailTagHelper.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace AuthoringTagHelpers.TagHelpers
{
    public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "a";    // Replaces <email> with <a> tag
        }
    }
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using eWeb.Models
@using eWeb.Models.AccountViewModels
@using eWeb.Models.ManageViewModels
@using AuthoringTagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers
```

This is the snippet of HTMLfrom an index.cshtml:

```
<address>
    <strong>Support:</strong><email>Support</email><br />
    <strong>Marketing:</strong><email>Marketing</email>
</address>
```

As I mentioned, nothing is happening.

Thank you,

Comment: Doesn't it work with `@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers.TagHelpers`?

Comment: Replacing this in the _ViewImports.cshtml did not make a difference (@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers.TagHelpers)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue, that the @addTagHelper in _ViewImports has to be the name of the assembly (eWeb in my case)